# Probability of the same number with 2 dice four times

Tags: probability

My two sons were playing snakes and ladders with two dice.

They rolled the same numbers four times in a row. It wasn't just the same total number but the same numbers. My younger son rolled a 4 and a 3, than my older son rolled a four and a three. This happened four times in a row.

What is the probability of that happening

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself?  For instance, do you know how many possible outcomes there are for a single roll of two dice? Do you know how many of those outcomes result in a $4$ and a $3$?

Comment: Were they all in the same sequence, too , ie $43-43-43-43$ ?

Comment: Remember [Littlewood's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_law): a person can expect to experience events with odds of one in a million (referred to as a "miracle") at the rate of about one per month

Answer (score 0):

To start with, let's figure out the probability of this sort of roll happening once. There are thirty six ways for two dice to roll, and out of those, two of them are a 3 and a 4 (one where the three is rolled first, and one where the four is rolled first). This comes out to a probability of $\frac{2}{36}$ or $\frac{1}{18}$. The probability of this happening 4 times in a row would therefore be $\frac{1}{18}^4$ or $\frac{1}{104,976}$.

This would be different for something like snake eyes, where the numbers are the same. The odds of rolling snake eyes is $\frac{1}{36}$, so the probability of rolling snake eyes four times in a row is $\frac{1}{36}^4$ or $\frac{1}{1,679,616}$

I suspect what you want to know is the probability of rolling the same combination of numbers 4 times in a row. This can be done by adding up the probabilities we calculated. There are 6 ways of rolling doubles, and 15 different pairs of different numbers that could be rolled, so the probability we are looking for is:
$$15(\frac{1}{18})^4+6(\frac{1}{36})^4=\frac{255}{1,679,616}=\frac{85}{559,872}\approx0.015\%$$